# Adding a list of equations to thesis

Tags: tocloft

I am trying to finish my final thesis manuscript. I am having problems with adding the List of Equations using `\usepackage{tocloft}`. The title "List of Equations" does not appear in all uppercase, instead only the first letter of "List" and "Equations" is uppercase, and the page does not have a roman number instead it has a arabic number. Also, when I try to create the List of Equations the titles of the other lists change from all caps to first letter caps only. How can I add the List of Equations with the title in all caps and the page number in roman?

Comment: Hi, welcome to TeX.SE --- could you be so kind and share an MWE (minimum working example) that shows what you currently have?